# I did not understand the feedback to use "standard flags"?

Tags: support

I voted to close a question as a duplicate. It was closed. And then reopened again. So I flagged it for moderator intervention with a message explaining why it is a duplicate. The flag was "declined" with the message:

> Declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

I also noticed that despite the flag being declined, the question has indeed been closed as a duplicate, as suggested. So I am confused. Isn't the "moderator intervention" flag for resolving community review issues where a question has been closed and reopened again?

Comment: The standard process for closure/reopening is to use a standard flag that places it in the queue, or to cast votes for closing/reopening directly or via the queue. The community's decision to borh close and reopen the question, and to then put it in queue for closure again, means the community is curating the question just fine. No moderator intervention is needed.

Comment: @Nij - Are you saying you either vote to close or you flag but you shouldn't do both?

Comment: You shouldn't be flagging for closure when you can vote, with one exception: you have no remaining votes for the day. If you have voted, a flag is pointless because they go to the same queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want a question to be closed as a duplicate, then choosing the "Duplicate" close reason has two additional effect:

1. When enough users also vote to close as duplicate, it gets closed without requiring moderator intervention
2. It goes to the review queue, prompting other users to cast votes as well

In addition, these flags *also* appear on the moderator dashboard, just like any others. So there is no reason to raise a custom flag and then use the text field to state nothing but that it's a duplicate. You are just creating additional work for the mod team, which is already rather overworked right now.